# LINQ Query for a complex data with grouping

Tags: linq

I have a complex data in this manner

```
<Complex Data>
      <Data Level 1>..........</Data>  (only single row)
      <Data>...................(n rows)
           <Data 2a>............</Data>  (only single row)
           <Data 2b>............</Data>  (n row)
           <Id></Id>.....................(unique key)
      </Data2>
</Complex Data>
```

I have a this complex data `LIST<COMPLEX DATA>` . I need to group this complex data using a element from `<Data 2a.......eg: Place> </Data2a>`

I try to implement this but i get only the child data type only `<Data 2a>` insted of parent data type `<Data2>`.

how can i convert this child data type into parent data type after grouping

how can i implement this in a for each loop.

Comment: is this XML? If not can you paste the class definition?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to group the complex data, then you should be using GroupBy in Linq and not using a for or for each loop

There are some simple group by examples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb738046 - the first example (in VB) should cover what you need?

Alternatively, this tutorial for LinqToXml grouping is quite good: http://msmvps.com/blogs/martin_honnen/archive/2009/11/27/grouping-with-linq-to-xml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
var grouping = source
    .SelectMany(x => x.Items.Select(y => Tuple.Create(x, y))
    .SelectMany(t1 => t1.Item2.Items.Select(z => Tuple.Create(t1.Item1, z))
    .GroupBy(t2 => t2.Item2, t2 => t2.Item1);
```

Its a bit ugly if you want to project, but maintain the reference to the source element this way...

The Item1 is your complext data, and Item2 your current projection. A nested foreach loop makes it more readable:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<K, TSource>> SelectManyKeys(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    foreach (var x in source)
    {
         foreach (var k in x.Items.SelectMany(z => z.Items))
         {
             yield return Tuple.Create(k, x);
         }
    }
}

var grouping = SelectManyKeys(source).GroupBy(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2));
```

Comment: hii Nappy, Thanks for ur reply... But i'm using .Net 3.5 it doesn't support Tuple.Create(). here is the query which i wrote var GroupBy = objMedData.Data.Select(FB => FB.Data.GroupBy(FF=>FF.PrimaryInsuranceID));  i got the result as an object of Data but i need the result as ComplexData

Comment: @CEEYES: Instead of tuples, you can also use anonymous types: `new { ComplexData = x, Projection = y }`.

Comment: hii Nappy Can u send me an example similar to my situation for this type. Because i'm new in LINQ....